# Scrape price from span tag using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape a price but I can't return anything. The span tag contains data-amount within it which I think could be causing the issue.

It looks like this

```
<span class="productPrice" data-amount style>€ 100.00</span>
```

I've tried:

```
price = soup.find("span", class_="productPrice").get_text()
```

But had no luck.

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion: try `.text` instead of `.get_text()`

Answer (score 0):

Code should looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('your_html_to_parse', 'html.parser')
span = soup.find("span", class_="productPrice")
print(span.text)
```

And result is in your case:

```
€ 100.00
```